# npm ERR! ngx-bootstrap@"^12.0.0" from the root project

Tags: angular, package.json, ngxs

I am upgrading to Angular 16; However, I don't know which version I should modify for the dependencies below:

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^16.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^17.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@12.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm ERR!   ngx-bootstrap@"^12.0.0" from the root project
```

Here is the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        ...
        "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
        ...
    },
```

Can you explain to me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: So your `ngx-bootstrap@12` requires `@angular/animations@^17`, but you only have 16th version, so lower `ngx-bootstrap` requirement to 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade `ngx-bootstrap` to v11.

`v12` requires Angular v17.